# Is there a way I can get bid/ask price data on the NSE in real time?

Tags: stocks, india, trading, market-data

I need bid/ask price live data on the National Stock Exchange of India to find out what buyers and sellers are quoting on the stock market. My trading platform only provides the best bid/ask price and the volume of buyers and sellers but I need some more information. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data source for historical intra-day bid/ask price data for stocks?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9655/data-source-for-historical-intra-day-bid-ask-price-data-for-stocks)

Comment: What country? Is this India National Stock Exchange.

Comment: @JohnBensin - this is not a duplicate of the other question you have referred to. This question is asking about current real time data, the other question is asking about historical intra-day data. They are 2 different questions.

Comment: @user15209 - are you after historical data or live data, the use of "real time" in your title refers to live data. Please clarify.

Comment: Also please mention , the trading platform that you use. Some trading platforms in India can provide you access to real time order book but that will not be downloadable by you

Answer (score 1):

Yes apply for live and dynamic data (you may have to pay for this depending on your broker and your country) and look at the market depth.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few Banks/brokers offer direct terminals to NSE where you can see live prices.

Answer (score 1):

Buy Data products from NSE. You will get historical order book. The Live order book may not be available. https://www.nseindia.com/supra_global/content/dotex/data_products.htm

This link has all the data products that NSE can provide